# Attribute Error in python

Tags: python, object, dictionary, attributeerror

I am getting an attribute error for the following code :

```
coininfo = [ {} for k in range(0,numberOftrials)]

coininfo[i].append([x,outcome(x)])
```

The following is the exact error screen i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "pr1.py", line 22, in <module>
runsimulation(numberOftrials,numberOfcoins)
  File "pr1.py", line 19, in runsimulation
coininfo[i].append([x,outcome(x)])
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why would you be able to append() to a dict? append() is clearly a list method and not a dict method.

Comment: @user2799617: Since I am very new to python, I did not know there were two methods (list & dict). I just followed the instruction, given in a similar thread! I will be more careful next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run

```
coininfo = [ {} for k in range(0,numberOftrials)]
```

you end up with an array of dictionaries, not an array of arrays. Thus `coininfo[i]` is a dictionary, and you can't append to it.

My guess is that you want to change your first line to

```
coininfo = [ [] for k in range(0,numberOftrials)]
```

so you will instead have an array of arrays. Alternative, if you mean for your output to be an array of dictionaries, you may mean to have

```
coininfo[i][x] = outcome(x)
```

instead of

```
coininfo[i].append([x,outcome(x)])
```